# Return the values of a column, associated with the values returned by "summarise", used on another column

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I have a function which summarises the first best values for `abs` column.

```
abs5_fun <- function(x) {

...
  buysell <- group_by_at(buysell, vars(TIME,SECCODE, DAY))
  buysell$abs <- (buysell$PRICE.y - buysell$PRICE.x)/(buysell$PRICE.y + buysell$PRICE.x)/2
  abs1 <- as.data.frame(summarise(buysell, abs = (head(sort(abs),5)[1])))
  abs2 <- as.data.frame(summarise(buysell, abs = (head(sort(abs),5)[2])))
  abs3 <- as.data.frame(summarise(buysell, abs = (head(sort(abs),5)[3])))
  abs4 <- as.data.frame(summarise(buysell, abs = (head(sort(abs),5)[4])))
  abs5 <- as.data.frame(summarise(buysell, abs = (head(sort(abs),5)[5])))
  return(as.data.frame(list(abs1 = abs1, abs2 = abs2, abs3 = abs3, abs4 = abs4, abs5 = abs5)))
}
```

The input looks like:

```
head(dataframe)

DAY      NO      SECCODE BUYSELL      TIME ORDERNO ACTION   PRICE VOLUME TRADENO TRADEPRICE
1   1  265281 SU46020RMFS2       S 100142905  136109      1 67.0000    500      NA         NA
2   1 1973817 SU26212RMFS9       B 101622474  983190      1 64.0000      4      NA         NA
3   1 1988822 SU26212RMFS9       S 101635958  990616      1 70.0000      4      NA         NA
4   1 2120163 SU25077RMFS7       S 101857791 1055751      1 96.0000     50      NA         NA
5   1 2344802 SU26212RMFS9       S 102829364 1165773      1 69.9999      4      NA         NA
6   1 2358352 SU26212RMFS9       S 102905724 1165773      0 69.9999      4      NA         NA
```

The output:

```
abs5 <- abs5_fun(dataframe)

 abs1.TIME abs1.SECCODE abs1.DAY     abs1.abs abs2.TIME abs2.SECCODE abs2.DAY     abs2.abs abs3.TIME abs3.SECCODE
1     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      100 0.0014609644     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      100 0.0014609644     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2
2     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      101 0.0024485414     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      101 0.0024497609     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2
3     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      102 0.0019588639     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      102 0.0024509804     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2
4     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      103 0.0022021537     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      103 0.0022021537     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2
5     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      104 0.0009779834     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      104 0.0009779834     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2
6     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      105 0.0016360580     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      105 0.0018791211     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2
  abs3.DAY    abs3.abs abs4.TIME abs4.SECCODE abs4.DAY    abs4.abs abs5.TIME abs5.SECCODE abs5.DAY    abs5.abs
1      100 0.001461209     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      100 0.001461209     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      100 0.001485684
2      101 0.002450736     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      101 0.003181596     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      101 0.003188528
3      102 0.003660322     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      102 0.004152418     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      102 0.005174714
4      103 0.002688998     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      103 0.003926307     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      103 0.003926307
5      104 0.001100023     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      104 0.001100023     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      104 0.003165124
6      105 0.002445941     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      105 0.002689000     1e+08 SU24018RMFS2      105 0.005413142
```

I need to return the values of `VOLUME` associated with `abs1.abs`, `abs2.abs`, etc.

I've tried retrieving all possible combinations of `abs` and `VOLUME` for each `TIME` and `DAY` and then using `inner_join` and match by `abs`, `VOLUME` and all other columns, but the results are always biased with my large dataset.

I'd like to have a grouped tibble with first 5 best `abs` and associated `VOLUME` as a result, but I am not sure, how to use `summarise` in this case. The question is, that I should add to this part of the function:

```
  abs1 <- as.data.frame(summarise(buysell, abs = (head(sort(abs),5)[1])))
  abs2 <- as.data.frame(summarise(buysell, abs = (head(sort(abs),5)[2])))
  abs3 <- as.data.frame(summarise(buysell, abs = (head(sort(abs),5)[3])))
  abs4 <- as.data.frame(summarise(buysell, abs = (head(sort(abs),5)[4])))
  abs5 <- as.data.frame(summarise(buysell, abs = (head(sort(abs),5)[5])))
```

Comment: Why don't you just left_join the results?

Comment: I've used inner_join but that number of observations in the result is always incorrect even if I delete duplicates. I'd like to get it directly from summarise.